# What Windows tools/editors are available for editing CWEB documents?

Tags: editor

I occasionally come across source code written in the CWEB standard that Donald Knuth promotes.  Are there any Windows tools and/or editors that can facilitate working with source code in that format?  At a minimum, syntax highlighting must be supported.
I am looking for options other than various Windows port of Vim.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer to my own question: Windows ports of Vim.

Answer (score 0):

> At a minimum, syntax highlighting must be supported

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor can be [easily configured](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=236) for alomst any programming language.